# $this->redirect display blank page in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My code is :

```
public function join_membership() 
{
    $this->layout = 'colorbox';
    $membership_id = $this->Cookie->read('membership_id');
    $membership =  $this->Membership->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Membership.id'=>$membership_id)));
    $this->set('membership',$membership); 
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if($this->JoinMembership->save($this->request->data['JoinMembership']))
        {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'member_login'));
        }
    }
}
```

This code save the data in database properly but after that it displays blank page, it doesn't redirect to the given function.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: I got same problem in recent project was due to whitespaces,
check that cookies are working or not

Comment: Cookies are working properly. I am getting desired value from cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code into your if condition.

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Controller_Name', 'action' => 'member_login'));
```

You can also try to print something into `if condition` you used. Also use the else part and also print something into `else part`. Check it in debug mode 2.

Comment: still blank, I think it's problem of white space in any file

Comment: ok, then try to use `ob_start();` before redirecting code in `if condition`. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I got it now I have added a component which contain white space in end of file. Now it's working fine

Comment: If you can't find the whitespace, I posted some code in an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody has trouble telling where their whitespace/output is (like I did), put this small block right before your `$this->redirect` call:

```
$file = '';
$line = '';
if (headers_sent($file, $line)) {
    die('Output in ' . $file . ' at line ' . $line);
}
```

It will stop your controller action and print out the exact file and line where the whitespace/output is.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is the member_login action located in the same controller as join_membership? If no then add the Controller => "Some_Controller" key value paire to the array.

2) If one does not work, check if the if condition is working like so

```
    if($this->JoinMembership->save($this->request->data['JoinMembership']))
            {

                debug("in");exit();

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'member_login'));
            }
        }
```

You should see "in" message if the if condition is returning true.

Please note that you can use

```
$this->redirect("action_name");
$this->redirect("/controller_name/action_name");
```

Comment: problem is still there. It's displaying blank page by using several redirect syntax

Comment: Ok then, I assume that you checked the two points above if so. Now go to member_login function and add debug exit functions to it. As it could be that this method redirecting correctly and but the logic in the other method is not working. Also please check if JoinMembership->save contains any redirections because it can be that you having several redirections taking place and the browser just stops following them after 4 concequtive redirections.